# Bootstrap dropdown button style at focus and unfocus

Tags: css, focus

I use bootstrap and I recorded my problem [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTdO51F3Jkg)

When I focus button dropdown he take other background-color and at unfocus disappear border. What class from css(bootstrap.css) need to edit to put my own colors and make to don't disappear border at unfocus?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="meniu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><b>Link</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Link</b></a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><b>Dropdown</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class ="active" ><a href="proiecte">Proiecte</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to edit dropdown and dropdown-toggle but i didn't found those classes with focus(class:focus).

Comment: post your css code or fiddle link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ovewrite this CSSin your custom CSS with !important

```
.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover {
    background-color: gray!important;
    border-color: #337ab7!important;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
    color: #262626!important;
    background-color: #f5f5f5!important;
}
```

Comment: Now color work perfect, but border still disappear at unfocus.